# how to write VBA code to hide some cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following script in automate enterprise system, which is used to hide some cells in the excel file. But it showing

> *Activex bad index*

The code is as follows

```
Sub Main

    Windows("InTransitReport - WELLFOAKL.xls").Activate
   Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Shipments").Select
    Range("Q5").Select
  Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
   Range("R5").Select
  Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Range("T5").Select
   Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Range("U5").Select
   Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Range("V5").Select
   Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
   Range("W5").Select
 Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
     Range("X5").Select
   Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Range("Y5").Select
   Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
   Range("AA5").Select
  Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Range("AB5").Select
   Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True`enter code here`
  Range("AC5").Select
   Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Range("A6").Select
   Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("POs").Select
    Range("A6").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You *wrote* this or recorded this? If you wrote this, then you should read up on avoiding the use of `.Select`. Edit: Yes, I can see that this was written due to the indention methodology used. Definitely read up on avoiding the use of `.Select` as it's not only slow but a nightmare to manage properly.

Comment: So, are these ranges ever going to change - or are they always the same ranges that need to be hidden?

Comment: Ignoring the "bad index" error, this could be written as: `Workbooks("InTransitReport - WELLFOAKL.xls").Sheets("Shipments").Range("Q1:R1,T1:Y1,AA1:AC1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the "bad index" error, this could be written as:

```
Workbooks("InTransitReport - WELLFOAKL.xls").Sheets("Shipments"). _
      Range("Q1:R1,T1:Y1,AA1:AC1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

If you're getting "index out of range" then either your workbook or worksheet name (or both) could be mis-spelled.

Answer (score 1):

Just quickly loop through those columns and hide them.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks("InTransitReport - WELLFOAKL.xls")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Shipments")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 17 To 29
        Select Case i
        Case 19, 26 'These weren't listed as a column to hide
        Case Else
            ws.Columns(i).Hidden = True
        End Select
    Next

    wb.Worksheets("POs").columns(6).Hidden = True

End Sub
```